# preamble for doppler shift estimation

Tags: digital-communications

To estimate the doppler shift in a multiuser communication, I use preambles (PN codes). When I send the preambles with the datas (BPSK symbol), the estimation for the doppler shift are not correct. But with just the preambles and no datas the estimations are correct.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Sorry, this is impossible to answer. You'll have to explain how you're doing the estimation, based on what, how you know it's wrong, and so on. More context!

Comment: How would we know!! Include more mathematics and codes to try to help you.